# How to read data from a file as a Graph (GraphX)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm new to Scala, and am trying to read an undirected graph as a Graph(GraphX) from a text file. The text file is has the format:

```
1,8,9,10
2,5,6,7,3,1
```

representing that node 1 is connected to nodes 8,9 and 10(adjacency list) and node 2 is connected to nodes 5,6,7,3,1.

I am trying to read this as a Graph(GraphX)

I'm trying to accomplish this using the fromEdge[VD,ED] method(GraphX), where I have to pass pairs of edges.

```
 val graph = sc.textFile("Path to file").map(line=>line.split(",").map(line=>line.toLong)).map{case Array(a,z @ _*)=>(z.map(m=>(a,m) ))}
```

This gives me,

```
Vector((1,8), (1,9), (1,10))
Vector((2,5), (2,6), (2,7), (2,3), (2,1))
```

Since graph is of type Unit, it can't be used with the fromEdge method(GraphX).

I am not able to figure out a way to make Edges from these. 
Is there a better way to do this?

Could anyone help me with this, or provide me with some resources that might help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are many versions of a solution can be written in Spark/Scala to load a graph from the file format you specified.

**Here is an example of a dynamic solution using RDD:**

```
// Loading sample data
scala> val graphData = sc.parallelize(Seq("1, 8, 9, 10", "2,5,6,7,3,1"))
graphData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[5]

// Trim whitespaces and map the String into an Array[Long]
scala> val graphList = graphData.map( x => {
     |    x.replace(" ", "").split(",").map(_.toLong)
     | })
graphList: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Long]] = MapPartitionsRDD[6]

// Here is how graphList looks like now
scala> graphList.collect
res11: Array[Array[Long]] = Array(Array(1, 8, 9, 10), Array(2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 1))

// Generating edges by crossProduct element(0) with the rest of Array elements
scala> val edges = graphList.flatMap(x => x.drop(1).map(y => (x(0), y) )).map(x => Edge(x._1, x._2, "attr"))
edges: Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[String]] = Array(Edge(1,8,attr), Edge(1,9,attr), Edge(1,10,attr), Edge(2,5,attr), Edge(2,6,attr), Edge(2,7,attr), Edge(2,3,attr), Edge(2,1,attr))

// Generating vertices, and adding name/attr for each vertex
scala> val vertices = graphList.flatMap(x => x).map(x => (x, ("name", "attr"))).distinct.sortBy(x => x)
vertices: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, (String, String))] = MapPartitionsRDD

//A default value is defined in case a connection or vertex is missing; the graph is then constructed from the RDD-based structures vertices and edges and the default record:
val default = ("Unknown", "Missing")

// Finally, declare your Graph
scala> val graph = Graph(vertices, edgesRDD, default)
graph: org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph[(String, String),String] = org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.GraphImpl@8097e8f

// Checking how vertices look like
scala> graph.vertices.collect
res26: Array[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, (String, String))] = Array((8,(name,attr)), (1,(name,attr)), (9,(name,attr)), (10,(name,attr)), (2,(name,attr)), (3,(name,attr)), (5,(name,attr)), (6,(name,attr)), (7,(name,attr)))
```

**Note** you should also consider partitioning (for parallelism) and caching (Vertices, Edges) to optimize your job further.

**A better way of constructing a Graph**

[GraphFrames](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/03/03/introducing-graphframes.html) is a better alternative to GraphX now, which benefit from the scalability and high performance of DataFrames.

I encourage you to read about it and start using it if possible.

**A more native format to represent a graph for GraphX or GraphFrames**

As an example, here is a vertex file contains just six lines. Each vertex represents a person and has a vertex ID number, a name, and attributes, in this case an age value:

```
1,Mike,48
2,Sarah,45
3,John,25
4,Jim,53
5,Kate,22
6,Flo,52
```

Another edge file contains a set of directed edge values in the form source vertex ID, destination vertex ID, and relationship. So, record 1 forms a Sister relationship between Flo and Mike:

```
6,1,Sister
1,2,Husband
2,1,Wife
5,1,Daughter
5,2,Daughter
3,1,Son
3,2,Son
4,1,Friend
1,5,Father
1,3,Father
2,5,Mother
2,3,Mother
```

Now your code will become as simple as:

```
val vertex = spark.read.option("header","true").load("csvgraph1_vertex.csv")
val edges = spark.read.option("header","true").load("csvgraph1_edges.csv")
val graph = GraphFrame(vertex, edges)
```

**Update**

**GraphFrames integrate with GraphX**

GraphFrames fully integrate with GraphX via conversions between the two representations, without any data loss. We can convert our graphs to a GraphX graph and back to a GraphFrame.

```
val gx: Graph[Row, Row] = g.toGraphX()
val g2: GraphFrame = GraphFrame.fromGraphX(gx)
```

Comment: hi @aelbuni do you know how to store and load graph to/from disk.